# JavaScript Objects: what is this repl test looking for?

Tags: javascript

I am working on developing some objects within custom functions in JavaScript.

I wrote a piece of code like this:

```
function updateObject(obj) {
    var obj = {
        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar',
        bizz: 'bizz',
        bang: 'bang'
    };

    return obj;
}

console.log(updateObject());
```

I know this is not wrong in that it outputs an object with key:value pairs in the console, but it fails this test suite from Repl:

```
/* test suite */
(function testUpdateObject() {
  var oldObj = {
    cats: 'cats',
    dogs: 'dogs',
  };
  var newObj = updateObject(oldObj);
  if (typeof newObj !== 'object') {
    console.error('ERROR: `createMyObject` must return an object');
    return false
  }
  ['foo', 'bar', 'bizz', 'bang'].forEach(function(key) {
    if (!(key in newObj)) {
      console.error('ERROR: `' + key + '` not in object returned by `updateObject`');
      return false;
    }
  });
  ['foo', 'bar', 'bizz', 'bang'].forEach(function(key) {
    if (newObj[key] !== key) {
      console.error('ERROR: `' + key + '` should be "' + key + '" but was ' + newObj[key]);
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (!(newObj.cats === 'cats' && newObj.dogs === 'dogs')) {
    console.error('ERROR: your function doesn\'t preserve existing key/value pairs');
    return false;
  }
  console.log('SUCCESS: `updateObject` works correctly!');

})();
```

Specifically, the function fails to preserve existing key/value pairs. This is what I am trying to resolve.

I also tried it with dot notation and square bracket notation like so:

```
function updateObject(obj) {
    var obj = {};
    {
      obj.foo ='foo',
        obj.bar ='bar',
        obj.bizz ='bizz',
        obj.bang ='bang'
    }
    return obj;
}
```

and

```
function updateObject(obj) {
    var obj = {};
     {
      obj['foo'] ='foo';
        obj['bar'] ='bar';
        obj['bizz']  ='bizz';
        obj['bang']  ='bang';
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Both cases `console.log(updateObject());`.

I am out of ideas as to how to write this custom function with object that will pass the test where it preserves key/value pair and I am looking for some guidance on how to figure this out.

I have been unable to find a Stack Overflow article that speaks directly to this case, nor have I found any documentation online that speaks to how to write a function that preserves existing key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never update the object, because you assign a new object to the given variable/parameter. You need to keep the array and assign the values step by step, or use, with ES6 [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
function updateObject(obj) {
    obj = obj || {};
    obj.foo = 'foo';
    obj.bar = 'bar';
    obj.bizz = 'bizz';
    obj.bang = 'bang';
    return obj;
}

console.log(updateObject());

(function testUpdateObject() {
    var oldObj = {
        cats: 'cats',
        dogs: 'dogs',
    };
    var newObj = updateObject(oldObj);
    if (typeof newObj !== 'object') {
        console.error('ERROR: `createMyObject` must return an object');
        return false
    }
    ['foo', 'bar', 'bizz', 'bang'].forEach(function (key) {
        if (!(key in newObj)) {
            console.error('ERROR: `' + key + '` not in object returned by `updateObject`');
            return false;
        }
    });
    ['foo', 'bar', 'bizz', 'bang'].forEach(function (key) {
        if (newObj[key] !== key) {
            console.error('ERROR: `' + key + '` should be "' + key + '" but was ' + newObj[key]);
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (!(newObj.cats === 'cats' && newObj.dogs === 'dogs')) {
        console.error('ERROR: your function doesn\'t preserve existing key/value pairs');
        return false;
    }

    console.log('SUCCESS: `updateObject` works correctly!');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't overwrite your parameter ...

```
function updateObject(obj) {
      obj['foo'] ='foo';
        obj['bar'] ='bar';
        obj['bizz']  ='bizz';
        obj['bang']  ='bang';
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're redefining obj when you say "var obj". remove the var. Updated code below.

```
function updateObject(obj) {
    var newObj = {
        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar',
        bizz: 'bizz',
        bang: 'bang'
    };

    // Apply all props of newObj to oldObj, while preserving oldObj
    return Object.assign(obj, newObj);
}
```

be aware that changing the original object is enough if you want to update it, you technically don't have to return the updated object (reference is preserved when you pass it into the function), but it's probably good practice to anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!(newObj.cats === 'cats' && newObj.dogs === 'dogs')) {
    console.error('ERROR: your function doesn\'t preserve existing key/value pairs');
    return false;
  }
```

So the problem is you don't preserve existing key/value pairs.

Since you redefine obj with a var, instead of adding the new properties to it, you  overwrite all of the old pairs.

So the correct way is editting the obj that gets inputted instead of redefining it. You could add them manually:

```
function updateObject(obj) {
    obj.foo = 'foo';
    obj.bar = 'bar';
    obj.bizz = 'bizz';
    obj.bang = 'bang';
    return obj;
}
```

Or you could use the relatively new `Object.assign()` method to merge two objects into eachother if your browser supports it:

```
function updateObject(obj) {
    var extension = {
        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar',
        bizz: 'bizz',
        bang: 'bang'
    };
    return Object.assign( obj, extension );
}
```